# same rails path displays different template if flash messages are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I came across an interesting problem when I try to alter what gets display if page is certain route'

```
<body>
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
    <!---both logged_in and is_admin are in session_helper-->
    <%if current_page?(login_path) or current_page?(signup_path)%>
        <p class = "title">CLOUD SOLAR</p>
    <% else %>
        <% if logged_in?%>
            <% if is_admin?%>
                <%= link_to "All Users", users_path%>
            <% end%>
            <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user)%>
            <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: "delete"%>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path%>
            <%= link_to "Log in", login_path%>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>
    <!-- <%=debug(params) if Rails.env.development?%> -->
</body>
```

In the code above, I am attempting to get rid of the "sign up" and "log in" link if the current page is either sign up or log in. The above code works fine until I test it with an incorrect email and password. When I test it with a wrong password, a flash message pops up (which it should!), but for some reason the Sign Up and Log in link also pops up underneath it also.

Given the code above, I thought that if the current route is login_path or signup_path, it will never get into the else part of the condition, but somehow it did.

What is going on here? Is the route somehow being altered when I input wrong information even though the  url still displays localhost:3000/login or localhost:3000/signup ??

Edit: For clarification, the title disappears completely if the login form has some sort of error. What is replaced is a new login-form and a flash error message. Where did the title CLOUD SOLAR go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing login_path and signup_path to login_url and signup_url. Another option would be to hardcode the paths.

```
current_page?(Rails.env.production? ? 'http://your_live_url/signup' : 'http://localhost:3000/signup')
```

Also, you could check the documentation here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Comment: How would the above link change when it's in production? Edit: just kidding answered!

Comment: See my edit. With this solution the link would use the live url in production only.

Comment: I ended up just change it from render to redirect_to to somehow fix the problem. I'll try your method when launching into production though!